# How, exactly, first function works?

Tags: python

Just started my coding journey, and not sure why this function works:

```
import math
def multiply(*args):
    args = int(args[0])
    arg_length = len(str(abs(args)))
    return args * (5 ** arg_length)
    pass
```

...and this one doesn't:

```
import math
def multiply(*args):
    arg_length = len(str(abs(int(args))))
    return args * (5 ** arg_length)
    pass
```

Does [0] exclude the '-' from the argument? If so, how does it not exclude first character if arg > 0?

Comment: It would help if you explain what the *multiply()* function is meant to achieve. What did you expect *int(args)* to do in your second code fragment (apart from trigger a TypeError exception)?

Comment: How would *you* explain `args`, in your own words? This might lead you to your own answer.

Comment: "Does [0] exclude the '-' from the argument?": I don't see any '-'; where does that come from?

Comment: Have a read through the tutorial, in particular [section 4.8.4. Arbitrary Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first function, `multiply(*args)` receives the arguments as a tuple. Then you overwrite it with `args=int(args[0])`. Now it is not a tuple, but an integer.

In the second function, you don't pick the first element of `args` to overwrite it. It is still a tuple and casting it to integer (`int(args)`) does not work.